# Merging pivot results

Tags: sql, join, pivot

I'm attempting to pivot a few values into columns but I can't seem to make them all end up in the same row. I'm not sure if there's a way to just specifically write a pivot query or if there's something wrong with how I'm attempting to join them. Because you probably know better than myself, Stackoverflow, I'll leave my terrible attempts out and try to explain it...

```
    select 
    [CARRIAGE_ID]
   ,[PUBLISH_FLAG]
   ,[COUNTER_PRESCRIBED]
   ,[ADT] AS 'ADT2008'
   ,[AWT] AS 'AWT2008'
   ,[AWE] AS 'AWE2008'
   from [RISSxplr].[dbo].[ADT_MAP_FACT]
   pivot (max([FIGURE]) FOR COUNT_TYPE IN ([ADT],[AWT],[AWE])) AS pCountType
   WHERE [COUNT_YEAR] = 2008
```

Gives me a result like (sample):

```
CARRIAGE_ID  PUBLISH_FLAG  COUNTER_PRESCRIBED  ADT2008   AWT2008  AWE2008
  10041           1                P            NULL      NULL     36800
  10041           1                P            NULL      46400    NULL
  10041           1                P            43000     NULL     NULL
```

These all share the same CARRIAGE_ID and what I need is for them to all be in the same row so it'd look like this:

```
  CARRIAGE_ID  PUBLISH_FLAG  COUNTER_PRESCRIBED  ADT2008   AWT2008  AWE2008
     10041          1               P             43000     46400    36800
```

But I can't seem to make that happen. Help please! And thank you, as always.

EDIT: I'll add sample data from ADT_MAP_FACT

```
CARRIAGE_ID COUNT_TYPE  COUNT_YEAR  FIGURE  NUMBER_DAYS PUBLISH_FLAG    COUNTER_PRESCRIBED
    10041       ADT        2008      43000      341           1               P
    10041       ADT        2009      43400      292           1               P
    10041       ADT        2010      44000      314           1               P
    10041       ADT        2011      43300      341           1               P
    10041       ADT        2012      42700      354           1               P
    10041       AWE        2008      36800      95            1               P
    10041       AWE        2009      36800      81            1               P
    10041       AWE        2010      37900      87            1               P
    10041       AWE        2011      37000      98            1               P
    10041       AWE        2012      36500      98            1               P
    10041       AWT        2008      46400      192           1               P
    10041       AWT        2009      46900      162           1               P
    10041       AWT        2010      47100      185           1               P
    10041       AWT        2011      46900      189           1               P
    10041       AWT        2012      46600      198           1               P
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need aggregates and a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    [CARRIAGE_ID]
   ,[PUBLISH_FLAG]
   ,[COUNTER_PRESCRIBED]
   ,MAX([ADT]) AS 'ADT2008'
   ,MAX([AWT]) AS 'AWT2008'
   ,MAX([AWE]) AS 'AWE2008'
FROM [RISSxplr].[dbo].[ADT_MAP_FACT]
PIVOT (MAX([FIGURE]) FOR COUNT_TYPE IN ([ADT],[AWT],[AWE])) AS pCountType
WHERE [COUNT_YEAR] = 2008 
GROUP BY     [CARRIAGE_ID]
            ,[PUBLISH_FLAG]
            ,[COUNTER_PRESCRIBED]
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86cfb9/1/0)

Comment: your query will output `10041, 1,  P,  NULL,  NULL ,36800` , you need to sum the AWT_ flds!

Comment: Well the GROUP BY thing, whilst working in the fiddle posted above, is not working in mine. Not sure what you mean by needing an aggregate on the fields (still learning SQL bit by bit), but I could try that! Thanks!

Comment: Updated using your data.

Comment: Well Goat, I'm not sure why it wasn't working. My query LOOKED the same from what I could tell, but after simply copy pasting yours over mine in a vain last attempt to make it work, it seems to work perfectly now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

As Group by , displays the first row encountered , so you have to use aggregate function (MAX/SUM) to get the desired result.

Try this,

```
select 
    [CARRIAGE_ID]
   ,[PUBLISH_FLAG]
   ,[COUNTER_PRESCRIBED]
   ,sum([ADT]) AS 'ADT2008'
   ,sum([AWT]) AS 'AWT2008'
   ,sum([AWE]) AS 'AWE2008'
   from [RISSxplr].[dbo].[ADT_MAP_FACT]
   pivot (max([FIGURE]) FOR COUNT_TYPE IN ([ADT],[AWT],[AWE])) AS pCountType
   WHERE [COUNT_YEAR] = 2008
group by [CARRIAGE_ID],
         [PUBLISH_FLAG],
         [COUNTER_PRESCRIBED];
```

check this fiddle here -> [fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7777a/3/0)

Comment: Same thing unfortunately. It won't bring the 3 values into the same row and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Guessing it's not MySQL, so you'd need all 3 fields in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Sorry, sorry, yeah MSSQL and I've added them but it's not working. Maybe it's the way the ADT_MAP_FACT table is structured or something I don't know. Real confused.

Comment: If you add sample data to your question we could probably nail it down.

Comment: Added! Let me know if you can see anything. Cheers!